# VBA Excel pulling new webpage data after clicking on "submit"

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to pull some info from a website that provides oil well data by API number (API is a unique number for every well in the US)

Website: http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellapi1

API example: 1708300502

The issue is, when I get to the 2nd page, IE.document.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).innerText still returns data from the initial page. How do I fetch the updated page data?

The ultimate goal is to get to the 2nd page, click on "30570" via IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click and then read the final 3rd page. I just cannot figure out how to read the updated page :(

```
Option Explicit

Sub sonris_WellData()
   Dim IE As InternetExplorer
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   IE.Visible = True

   Dim i As Integer

   'Open SONRIS website
   Application.StatusBar = "Opening Website"
   IE.navigate "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellapi1"
   Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
   Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
   Application.StatusBar = False

   IE.document.forms(0).p_apinum.Value = "1708300502" 'plug-in API
   IE.document.forms(0).submit

   ' Wait until the next page opens
   Application.StatusBar = "Opening Website"
   Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
   Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
   Application.StatusBar = False

   ' Read the page - this is where the issue occurs, MsgBox keeps returning text from the very 1st page
   MsgBox IE.document.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).innerText

   IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working. Rather than `DoEvents` use the WinAPI Sleep function. I also added a call to the `Sleep` function after the form submit.

MOre often we are seeing sites that are dynamically served by some javascript/etc., in these cases the browser may appear to be `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` or not `Busy` but the page has not yet rendered the "new" results.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub sonris_WellData()
   Dim IE As Object 'InternetExplorer
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   IE.Visible = True

   Dim i As Integer

   'Open SONRIS website
   Application.StatusBar = "Opening Website"
   IE.navigate "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellapi1"
   Do While IE.readyState <> 4
       Sleep 1000
   Loop

   Application.StatusBar = False

   IE.document.forms(0).p_apinum.Value = "1708300502" 'plug-in API
   IE.document.forms(0).submit

   Sleep 1000

   ' Wait until the next page opens
   Application.StatusBar = "Opening Website"
   Do While IE.readyState <> 4
    Sleep 1000
   Loop

   Application.StatusBar = False

   ' Read the page - this is where the issue occurs, MsgBox keeps returning text from the very 1st page
   MsgBox IE.document.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).innerText

   IE.Quit
End Sub
```

You can experiment maybe with a slightly longer `Sleep` after the `.submit`.

Alternatively, I notice that after you submit, the URL changes, so you could also try changing the second waiting loop to:

```
Do While IE.LocationURL ="http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellapi1"
    Sleep 1000
Loop
```

This should put the Excel.Application to wait until the URL has changed.

Alternatively, you may have better luck using an XMLHTTPRequest (there are many examples of this here on SO and elsewhere on the internet).  This allows you to send a request just like the browser, without actually using a web browser.  Then you can simply parse the return text as HTML or XML.  I would use the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library reference for this.

Comment: Still no luck. I can see pages loading up, so the delay is not the case. I'll trying using XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: Oooh sorry try the second suggestion `Do While IE.Location = "http://...`" I used the wrong operator there.

Comment: Even after I wait for 10-15 seconds, IE.LocationURL returns the 1st link (http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellapi1) even though the page has been on the 2nd for over 5 seconds: "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellapi2"

Comment: Try the second suggestion... loop based on the `IE.Location`.

Comment: nothing happens. I re-programmed script so that it'd write down IE.LocationURL every 5 second on a new row. The result is that it keeps pulling data from the old IE page, not the new one :(

Answer (score 1):

## **POST requests:**

**① Entering the Well API number**

I examined the web page making the selections you mention. I inspected the web traffic using [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and noticed that the initial request, when you submit the API number is handled by a [`POST` request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)).

[image: POST request]

---

**② POST request:**

The `POST` body has the following parameter:

[image: POST param]

`p_apinum` is the key and the associated value is the original Well API number.

Using this info I formulated a POST request direct thus avoiding your first landing page.

---

**③ Pressing the hyperlink:**

Next, I noticed that the element you wanted to press:

[image: Hyperlink]

Looking at the associated HTML it has an associated relative hyperlink:

[image: HTML]

I use a helper function to parse the page HTML to get this relative link and construct the absolute path: `GetNextURL(page.body.innerHTML)`.

---

**④ Making a new request:**

I re-use my HTTPRequest function `GetPage` to send a second request, with an empty body, and grab all the tables from the HTML document returned via: `page.getElementsByTagName("table")`.

---

**⑤ Writing the tables to the Excel worksheet:**

I loop all the tables on the page using helper function  `AddHeaders` to write out the table headers, and  `WriteTables` to write the current table to the sheet.

---

**Example page content:**

[image: Example page content]

---

**Example code output:**

[image: Code output]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetWellInfo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, page As HTMLDocument, targetTable As HTMLTable, apiNumbers(), currNumber As Long
    Const PARAM1 As String = "p_apinum"
    Const BASESTRING As String = "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/"
    apiNumbers = Array(1708300502, 1708300503)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        .Cells.ClearContents
        For currNumber = LBound(apiNumbers) To UBound(apiNumbers)
            Set page = GetPage(BASESTRING & "cart_con_wellapi2", apiNumbers(currNumber), PARAM1)
            Set page = GetPage(BASESTRING & GetNextURL(page.body.innerHTML))
            Dim allTables As Object
            Set allTables = page.getElementsByTagName("table")
         
            For Each targetTable In allTables
                AddHeaders targetTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2, ws
                WriteTables targetTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1), ws
            Next targetTable
        
        Next currNumber
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetPage(ByVal url As String, Optional ByVal apiNumber As Long, Optional ByVal paramN As String = vbNullString) As HTMLDocument
    Dim objHTTP As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
  
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    Dim sBody As String
    If Not paramN = vbNullString Then sBody = paramN & "=" & apiNumber
    With objHTTP
        .SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        On Error Resume Next
        .send (sBody)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If .Status = "200" Then
                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                Set GetPage = html
            Else
                Debug.Print "HTTP " & .Status & " " & .statusText
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source & " " & Err.Description
            Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
 
End Function

Public Function GetNextURL(ByVal inputString As String)
    GetNextURL = Replace$(Replace$(Split(Split(inputString, "href=")(1), ">")(0), Chr$(34), vbNullString), "about:", vbNullString)
End Function

Public Sub AddHeaders(ByVal hTable As Object, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
    Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
    For Each header In headers
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        ws.Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
    Next header
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTables(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = startRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In tRow
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each td In tCell
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
            r = r + 1:  c = 1
        Next tr
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**References:**

VBE > Tools > References > HTML Object Library.